# Compare two tables with mysql through php

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have these two mysql tables:

```
country
----
username        Country
John            USA
Sarah           Canada
```

```
fav_color
----
username        Color
John            Blue
Sarah           Green
```

How can I select Sarah's favorite color, but ONLY if she is in Canada?

Something like:

```sql
SELECT color FROM fav_color WHERE name='sarah' AND username=(a canadian username)
```

Comment: This does seem a lot like a homework question to me, but I like that there are multiple succinct but different correct answers to this basic SQL question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select on the two tables and specify that you want to match records by username:

```
SELECT color FROM fav_color, country 
    WHERE fav_color.username='Sarah' AND
    fav_color.username = country.username AND
    country = 'Canada';
```

Answer (score 3):

A pretty straight forward JOIN;

```
SELECT color FROM fav_color f
JOIN country c ON c.username=f.username
WHERE c.username='Sarah'
  AND c.country='Canada';
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37bbd/9).

Answer (score 1):

How about using `WHERE EXISTS`?

```sql
SELECT color FROM fav_color
    WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT username FROM country
             WHERE country.username = fav_color.username
             AND country.Country = 'Canada')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select color from fav_color where 
    name='sarah' and 
    name in (
        select name from country where country='canada'
    )
```